# Ruby on Rails and JS - How get a object Json in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps

I have a Json with some informations using Ruby on Rails (I generate this through a method in a controller):

```
pis: [
{
kilometer: 621,
category: "fare",
name: "Guaraçaí",
toll: "false",
lat: -21.0059,
lng: -51.1904,
icon: "/img/icon_fare_map.png",
pedagios: [ ]
},
```

And the following function get the Json (this show markers in my Google Maps):

```
function getAllPI(){
 $.get("/map_pis", function(data){
  $(data.pis).each(function(){

   // Adds a marker for each Json item
   addMarker(this);

   // Show all markers
   showMarkers();
  })
 });
}
```

I just want to add the marker and show it if my field 'toll' in Json is 'true'. If is 'false' I dont wanna show. How can I do that? I tried with:

```
if (pis.toll == true ) {
 addMarker(this);
}
```

But that didn't work. I do not have much experience with Json.

Someone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your json, your toll value seems to be a string. Therefore doing

```
pis.toll == true
```

will always be `false`, as `"true"` is not equal to `true`

Maybe this will work

```
pis.toll == "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a parameter for your `.each` block, which refers to the specific item in the array you're working with.  Then you can check if the toll on that is true and if it is, add the marker.  I'm not sure if `this` is the argument you wanted to pass to that, but I would guess `item` is what you need.

```js
function getAllPI(){
 $.get("/map_pis", function(data){
  $(data.pis).each(function(item){

   // Adds a marker for each Json item
   if (item.toll) addMarker(item);

   // Show all markers
   showMarkers();
  })
 });
}
```

Comment: That way it does not work and also makes the points disappear from the map. :/